# GPG Different Passphrase for Subkey

Tags: pgp, gnupg

Is it possible to have a different passphrase for a GPG subkey?

The reason is that I'm using [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org) to back up my files, and it needs the key passphrase to sign the files.

Since I want run duplicity automatically, I would have to store the passphrase in an environment variable. I don't feel comfortable storing my main key's passphrase in an environment variable, so I'm wondering if I could have a different passphrase for the subkey that does the signing.

Comment: There are good answers for this here: https://superuser.com/questions/879977/how-to-have-a-different-pass-phrase-for-a-gpg-subkey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendation is to use a completely separate key.  Because you're signing backups, only you need to trust the separate key, so there's not a web of trust issue here.  You can even sign it with your main key, if you like.

A second option is to load a gpg-agent and load the key.  You'll need to set max-cache-ttl=-1 and default-cache-ttl=-1 to allow it to keep the key indefinitely.  You'll still need to type in the passphrase once per boot.  (I haven't tested the -1 options, that's based on reading the code that -1 is infinite.)

If you don't want to do that, you could copy your GNUPGHOME (~/.gnupg, typically), delete the other subkeys, and change the passphrase on the key.  Then have duplicity use this subkey-only installation with the new passphrase.  (Just set the GNUPGHOME environment variable to work with the different home directory.)

Comment: I'll take your advice and create a separate key, since it will also be easier to manage. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Easiest is to do the following steps:

1. create a new GPG home folder with the option `--homedir`
2. export the desired keys to a file
3. import that file to the new GPG home
4. removing all unneeded secrets
5. change the passphrase

This sounds a bit complicate like this, but in fact it is not [that difficult](https://yayimorphology.org/gpg-thunderbird.html#extracting-the-subkeys). The [edit mode](https://yayimorphology.org/gpg-thunderbird.html#gpg-edit-mode) of GPG is also very convenient.